# How to find ODE , with constant-coefficient ,homogeneous , with minmum power such that $y_3(x) = xe^x\sin^2(x)$, is soultion for it.

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

> find ODE , with constant-coefficient ,homogeneous , with minmum power such that $y_3(x) = xe^x\sin^2(x)$, is soultions for it. explain why it is minimum.

not sure how to explain that this ODE is minimal also not sure if it is right.

Possible answer ( might be wrong ) :

$ y^{(6)}-6y^{(5)}+23y^{(4)}-52y'''+79y''-70y'+25=0$
$\\$

> my trial :

by rewriting the solution $y_3(x)$ :

$y_3(x) = xe^x(\frac{1-\cos(2x)}{2})$ = $c_1xe^x + c_2 xe^x\cos(2x)$

so the solution they want is the set { $xe^x,xe^x\cos(2x)$}

first one : $xe^x = x^me^{rx}\rightarrow m = 1  , r =1$

so the special polynomial is :

$(1)$ $(r-1)^2 = 0$

second one : $xe^x\cos(2x) = x^1e^{(1+2i)x}$

so the special polynomial is :

$(2)$ $(r^2 -2r + 5)^2 = 0$

combine $(1)$,$(2)$ we get :

$F(r) = (r-1)^2(r^2 -2r + 5)^2$

or

F(r) = $ r^6 -6r^5 + 23r^4 - 52r^3 + 79r^2 - 70r + 25$

so our ODE is :

$ y^{(6)}-6y^{(5)}+23y^{(4)}-52y'''+79y''-70y'+25=0$

Answer (score 1):

Note that
$$
y(x)=x\,\mathrm{e}^x\sin^2x=\frac12x\,\mathrm{e}^x(1-\cos 2x)
$$
Thus $x\,\mathrm{e}^x$ and $x\,\mathrm{e}^x\cos 2x$ should satisfy our equation.

Hence, the characteristic polynomial $p(\lambda)$ of our equation should have $\lambda=1$ and $\lambda=1+i$ as roots, and both of multiplicity at least 2. Thus
$$
(\lambda-1)^2(\lambda^2-2\lambda+5)^2 \quad\text{divides}\quad p(\lambda)
$$
Therefore, of minimum degree such $p$ should be
$$
p(\lambda)=(\lambda-1)^2(\lambda^2-2\lambda+5)^2
$$

Comment: Since it is $\cos 2x$ did you intend $(\lambda-1)^2(\lambda^2-2\lambda+5)^2$?

Comment: @JohnWaylandBales Correct. Thanks!

Comment: You are welcome.

Answer (score 0):

Hint.

$$
\mathcal{L}\left(x e^x\sin^2x\right) = \frac{2 \left(3 s^2-6 s+7\right)}{(s-1)^2 \left(s^2-2 s+5\right)^2}
$$